# Chart Title Border Style and Color in Excel by python

Tags: pandas, xlsxwriter, excel-charts

I created a chart by `xlswriter` in python. 
Now I want to set the border for the chart title. 
what should I do?

code:

the code for creating the chart with the title is shown below.

```
new_df = pd.read_excel('Book2.xlsx')
X_Ls = new_df['X'].tolist()
Y_Ls = new_df['Y'].tolist()
Z_Ls = new_df['Z'].tolist()

bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})
headings = ['X_Ls', 'Y_Ls', 'Z_Ls']
data = [
        X_Ls,
        Y_Ls,
        Z_Ls,
        ]

worksheet11.write_row('A1', headings, bold)
worksheet11.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet11.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet11.write_column('C2', data[2])
line_chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
line_chart2.add_series({
                        'name':       '=Paging_KPI_prv!$C$1',
                        'categories': '=Paging_KPI_prv!$A$2:$A$32',
                        'values':     '=Paging_KPI_prv!$C$2:$C$32',
                        'y2_axis':    True,
                        'line': {'color': 'orange', 'width': 2.5}
                        })
column_chart2.combine(line_chart2)
column_chart2.set_title({  'name': 'Affected User',
                            'name_font':{'name':'Calibri(Body)','size':14}})
```

worksheet11.insert_chart('C18', chart2)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqs17.png)

I want the result as below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Njym.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Border and Fill formatting of the title box aren't currently supported in XlsxWriter. If you open a [feature request](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) it can be added.